# Writing a new column if entries match on different data frames Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm fairly new to Python and need some help with my data

Lets say my data 1 is

```
Year Population Country
1960            A
1998            A
1969 3          B
1999            B
..
2018 4          Z
```

And data 2 is

```
Year A     B     C     D
1960 2     4     3     3
1961 3     4     2     1
...
2018 3     4     1     3
```

Where [A, Z] are the countries

In data 1, the population is not filled for most countries and years, so I had to download the data for the population on a different set. Now I want to fill the entries in data 1 if the years and countries match on both data sets. I am struggling with this because the Columns in data 2 are each of the countries whereas in data 1, the countries are listed in only 1 column.

Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lookup`:

```
df2 = df2.set_index('Year')

df1['Population'] = df1['Population'].fillna(df2.lookup(df1['Year'], df1['Country']) )
```